# Anyone have a link/download to old version of AS3 & Flex API docs?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

The http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html has an incredibly slow search functionality. I use a greasemonkey search plugin that is much much faster and works with the standard style javadocs. Anyone have a link to the old version of the AS3 API docs that were of the standard style?

Comment: Why not just search on Google?  add 'help.adobe.com' to the end of your search.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I think he is refering to the old cfm that was pre-webdocs. Atleast I think it was a cfm file lol

Comment: I normally search Google in the format `livedocs {class} {method|property}`.

Comment: @The_asMan In that case; go here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/documentation.html and use the "Download all docs as zip" option.  I think it provides PDFs... I have no memory of pre-webdocs for AS3.

Comment: I was refering to the old AS3 10.0 docs which I found in a blog post describing how to integrate AS docs into FDT. Unfortunately I forgot to bookmark and am unable to locate the post. Anyway, I did download the 10.0 docs but they did not contain documentation for Flex making them useless. Looks like I'm stuck with the current docs with the terrible search and looking to see if airdoc is fast. Also, thanks a lot for the suggestion Marty Wallace I think that'll work really well. Unfortunately it looks like Google isn't a big fan of spark components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?
http://www.airdoc.be/